# How to call other functions with a firebase function? (html, javascript, web app)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a quiz web app (html, js) with an online leader board.

I'm trying to add score to firebase realtime database. I can succesfully add scores to firebase.

The problem is that when I try call other functions with the firebase function, then scores are not added to firebase.

This works:

```
function addData() {
  database.ref('/users/' + username.value).set({
    score: mostRecentScore
  })
}

saveScoreBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  addData();
});
```

This does not work (go back to start after score is added)

```
function addData() {
  database.ref('/users/' + username.value).set({
    score: mostRecentScore
  })
  window.location.assign('/')
}

saveScoreBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  addData();
});
```

Any ideas why this does not work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.assign('/')` causes the current page to immediately stop executing its code and load the next page.  This means that the write to the database will not complete.

You should be aware that Firebase's [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method returns a Promise, which means that it's asynchronous and returns immediately, before the write is complete.  You must use the promise to know when the data has been finally written.  Only then can you change the current page without losing data.  You should also check for errors and figure out what you want to do if something goes wrong.

```
function addData() {
  database.ref('/users/' + username.value).set({
    score: mostRecentScore
  })
  .then(() => {
    window.location.assign('/')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```